# Max URL Levels in Controller Magento 2

Tags: magento2, url, controllers

I have custom controller outputting JSON format which works well for the below URL level;

```
** Works
base url/module/folder/action
//equates to Vendor\Module\Controller\Folder\Index.php
```

However I would like some somewhat deeper nested URL endpoints as per below but I get 404 on controllers deeper that one folder;

```
**Hit with 404
base url/module/folder/anotherfolder/action
//equates to Vendor\Module\Controller\Folder\Anotherfolder\Index.php

/* or even deeper */

**Hit with 404 - not tested
base url/module/folder/anotherfolder/deeperfolder/action
//equates to Vendor\Module\Controller\Folder\Anotherfolder\Deeperfolder\Index.php
```

I'm guessing Magento2 doesn't allow deep nested URL types or controllers ...

For me, this deeper nesting would be ideal to have a more manageable controller development & access since we have lost the ability to have multiple actions/endpoints in the one controller (Magento 1.*) (advise if not the case)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For this path

```
Vendor\Module\Controller\Folder\Anotherfolder\Deeperfolder\Index.php
```

URL will be

```
url/module/folder_anotherfolder_deeperfolder/action
```

As per as magento URL format  is

> **URL/frontenName/ActionFolder/Action**

frontenName is defined at `routes.xml`

ActionFolder locates at Controller folder which can `multiple folders path` but path will connect `via (_) Undescore`

```
Action is the php class.
```

Comment: ideally I would prefer URL without underscores (underscores changed to forward slashes) but this would need additional rewrites programmatically (and not manually created via admin panel etc)

Answer (score 2):

In Magento Catalog module has very nice and simple example by adding any product to compare.

Url Action Is :-

```
http://127.0.0.1/magento/catalog/product_compare/index/
```

Your Layout is :-

```
catalog_product_compare_index.xml
```

Folder structure is :-

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Product/Compare/Index.php
```

It's very simple, magento has many examples.